# XML formatting result return error

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to return a XML structure format from a PHP file...I should get an expected result like:

```
<points srv="2381" id="1233"><point id="1233" value1="46" value2="11" value3="231" value4="5516" time_evento="2013-11-13 16:54:17" /><point id="1233"...
```

but I get an error with this obtained result:

```
.../parsererror.xml">XML parse error: illegal...: https://.../file.php <sourcetext>&lt;points srv="2381" id="1233"&gt;&lt;point id="1233" value1="46" value2="11" value3="231" value4="5516" time_evento="2013-11-13 16:54:17" /&gt;&lt;point id="1233"...
```

even if in the file I fwrite the result out it saved all correctly...

Here is the code:

```
while ($riga = $db->fetch_object($res))
{
        $rows_found = true;
        if ($riga->srv <> $prev_srv || $riga->id <> $prev_id) {
                if (!$bof) {
                        $xml_document .= '</points>';   // node header
                }
                $xml_document .= '<points srv="'.$riga->srv.'" id="'.$riga->id.'">';
                $bof = false;  
                $prev_srv = $riga->srv;
                $prev_id = $riga->id;
        }

        $xml_document .= '<point id="'.$riga->id.'" value1="'.$riga->val1.'" value2="'.$riga->val2.'" value3="'.$riga->val3.'" ';
        $xml_document .= ' value4="'.$riga->val4.'" ';
        $xml_document .= ' time_evento="'.$riga->time_evento.'"  />';
}
if ($rows_found) {
        $xml_document .= "</points>";
}

$myFile = "/var/tmp/resultXML";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $xml_document . "\n"); // <---- in the xml_document file I get the correct result
fclose($fh);   

// $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_document);
// echo $xml->asXML();

echo $xml_document;

$db->free_results($res);

if(session_id() == '') {
        session_write_close();
}              
return 0;
```

Any suggest? It's getting me a bit crazy and I am stuck about this since three days...

Comment: Well, it seems to be having trouble parsing the XML. What does the XML look like exactly at the point it's complaining about?

Comment: Hello Pekka, the XML result is like just a <points srv="" id=""><point .... /></points> where the <point ..... /> thing is repeated for all values that are similar to the <point id="1233" value1="46" value2="11" value3="231" value4="5516" time_evento="2013-11-13 16:54:17" /> ... even I thought also it could be a some strange character between >< because before I put also a \n at the end of <point .....> to go in a new line so I removed the \n thing to have all it like in only one line but nothing...

Comment: Is the above the full error message?

Comment: Hi Pekka, precisely the error is:"<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/locale/intl.css" type="text/css"?> <parsererror xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml">XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: https://x.x.x.x/file.php Line Number 5509, Column 10:<sourcetext>&lt;/points&gt;&lt;points srv="2381" id="1774"&gt; ---------^</sourcetext></parsererror>"

The matter is if I read the log file of result I fwrite in /var/temp it doesn't look any junk char...it seems it doesn't recognize correctly the "<" and ">" chars....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: it looks like the XML document has to have a root node otherwise it wouldn't be like well formed... like:

```
<root>
   <points ...>
      <point.... />
      <point.... />
      .
      .
      <point.... />
   </points>
   <points...>
      <point.... />
      <point.... />
      .
      .
      <point.... />
   </points>
</root>
```

Thanks anyway!

Cheers,
Luigi